# Add Custom Guard admin in the below query to fetch Admin ID Value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to add a custom guard to fetch User ID Value from the admin table?

```
$admin = $this->adminRepo->findAdminById(
auth()->user()->id  //add Custom Admin Guard Instead of Default Admin Guard
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a guard by this one

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id
```